# change multiple columns based on a condition and column name string

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

i have a very sparse data set - below is a example of the format. I want to make changes to specific columns based on the logic explained below

```
# create dummy data set
pb=c('1','0','0','0','0','1','Not_ans','1','0','Not_ans')
qa=c('1','1','0','0','1','0','Not_ans','1','Not_ans','Not_ans')
#zy=c('1','Not_ans','0','1','Not_ans','0','1','1','1','Not_ans')

#sub questions for pb
pb.abr=c('1','0','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','0')
pb.ras=c('0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0')
pb.sfg=c('1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0')

#sub questions for qa
qa.fgs=c('1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0')
qa.sdf=c('0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0')
qa.tyu=c('0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0')

df=data.frame(pb,qa,pb.abr,pb.ras,pb.sfg,qa.fgs,qa.sdf,qa.tyu)
df

        pb      qa pb.abr pb.ras pb.sfg qa.fgs qa.sdf qa.tyu
1        1       1      1      0      1      1      0      0
2        0       1      0      0      0      0      1      0
3        0       0      0      0      0      0      0      0
4        0       0      0      0      0      0      0      0
5        0       1      0      1      0      0      0      1
6        1       0      1      0      0      0      0      0
7  Not_ans Not_ans      0      0      0      0      0      0
8        1       1      1      1      1      1      0      1
9        0 Not_ans      0      0      0      0      0      0
10 Not_ans Not_ans      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

The two columns pb and qa are called base columns, and they have further sub columns for with naming convention as pb. and qa. - so we see three sub columns for pa and 3 for qa. I want to make changes to these sub columns based on a condition to the base column ( pa or qa) .

Condition is if column `pb =='Not_ans'` then make all sub columns (pb.abr,pb.ras and pb.sfg) = 'Not_applicable'

how do i write a function which achieves this? where i specify the base column name i.e. `pb` and naming of sub columns example `'pb.'` below - would it be something like below but it wont give the result

```
data.frame(ifelse(df['base_q']=='Not_ans',
df[ , grepl( paste('base_q','.') , names(df) )]=='Not_applicable',df[,grepl( 
paste('base_q','.') , names(df)) ])
```

How do i write a generic function which takes the base column numbers as inputs for example 1,2 here - applies the function i.e whereever pb is Not_ans it changes sub_columns ( pb.abr,pb.ras,pb.sfg) to Not applicable and then moves to column 2 ( qa) and applies the same logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer given by @Wen-Ben - the following code worked -

`yf=function(df,v,y){
  for(i in v:y) {
  df[df[i]=='Not_ans',][,names(df)[substr(names(df),1,nchar(colnames(df)[i])+1)==paste0(colnames(df)[i],'.')]]='Not_applicable'
  }
  return(df)
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can do with

```
yf=function(df,v){
   df[df[v]=='Not_ans',][,names(df)[substr(names(df),1,nchar(v)+1)==paste0(v,'.')]]='Not_applicable'
   return(df)
 }
yf(df,'pb')
        pb      qa         pb.abr         pb.ras         pb.sfg qa.fgs qa.sdf qa.tyu
1        1       1              1              0              1      1      0      0
2        0       1              0              0              0      0      1      0
3        0       0              0              0              0      0      0      0
4        0       0              0              0              0      0      0      0
5        0       1              0              1              0      0      0      1
6        1       0              1              0              0      0      0      0
7  Not_ans Not_ans Not_applicable Not_applicable Not_applicable      0      0      0
8        1       1              1              1              1      1      0      1
9        0 Not_ans              0              0              0      0      0      0
10 Not_ans Not_ans Not_applicable Not_applicable Not_applicable      0      0      0
```

Data input

```
df=data.frame(pb,qa,pb.abr,pb.ras,pb.sfg,qa.fgs,qa.sdf,qa.tyu,stringsAsFactors = F) 
# notice stringsAsFactors
```

Comment: Hi above solution works - but then do i use an lapply to apply it of the number of columns. Like in above data frame - i show two base columns but in my orignal data frame i have 100s of base question columns and 1000+s sub question columns. Naming convention follows as ('baseQ+".") but not for all. Would it make sense to have the function instead with input - base question column numbers & naming logic of sub questions

Comment: @Pb89 if you know your base columns you can just apply it just need to modify the function with for loop in it

Answer (score 0):

One way would be the following. You can specify which columns you want to apply a function (or functions) in `var` in `mutate_at()`. Here I used `contains()` to specify the column names. Then, I replaced the numeric values in the columns when pb == "Not_ans" with "Not_applicable".

```
mutate_at(df, 
          vars(contains("pb.")),
          .funs = funs(ifelse(pb == "Not_ans",
                              "Not_applicable",
                              .)))

#        pb      qa         pb.abr         pb.ras         pb.sfg qa.fgs qa.sdf qa.tyu
#1        1       1              2              1              2      1      0      0
#2        0       1              1              1              1      0      1      0
#3        0       0              1              1              1      0      0      0
#4        0       0              1              1              1      0      0      0
#5        0       1              1              2              1      0      0      1
#6        1       0              2              1              1      0      0      0
#7  Not_ans Not_ans Not_applicable Not_applicable Not_applicable      0      0      0
#8        1       1              2              2              2      1      0      1
#9        0 Not_ans              1              1              1      0      0      0
#10 Not_ans Not_ans Not_applicable Not_applicable Not_applicable      0      0      0
```

If you want to apply the same task for both `pb` and `qa`, you can use `mutate_at()` twice.

```
mutate_at(df, 
          vars(contains("pb.")),
          .funs = funs(ifelse(pb == "Not_ans",
                              "Not_applicable",
                              .))) %>%
mutate_at(vars(contains("qa.")),
          .funs = funs(ifelse(qa == "Not_ans", "Not_applicable",.)))
```

Comment: again, do i use `lapply` to apply it over a multiple number of base q columns?

Comment: @Pb89 You do not have to use `lapply()`. Basically, you are applying if_else() to all columns that begins with "pb.".

Comment: No I meant with this I would have to run the code for pb and then again for qa. How do I apply this mutate to both column 1,2 which end up changing the sub cols of pb and qa

Comment: Then, you can run mutate one more time. In the 2nd time, you change column names. So it would be something like `mutate_at(vars(contains("qa.")), .funs = funs(ifelse(qa == "Not_ans", "Not_applicable",.)))`

Comment: Like I mentioned if it was 2 columns, would have done that. But I have 100s of columns like pb and qa. And can't apply it one by one to all

Comment: @Pb89 It would be great if you would have mentioned such a detail in your original question.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but the last paragraph of the original questions does say a function with column numbers as inputs and applies the logic to all.